# $z=2-(x^2+y^2)$ cut off by the lines $x=0,y=1,y=x$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces

Find the surface area of $z=2-(x^2+y^2)$ cut off by the lines $x=0,y=1,y=x$

S.A.$=\int \int_{R} \sqrt{1+4(x^2+y^2)}dxdy$

Where we know that $R$ is the region bounded by $y=1,x=0,y=x$ and $x^2+y^2=(\sqrt{2})^2$

This is essentially the area bounded by $y=1,x=0,y=x$ as $\sqrt{2}>1$

The final integral i am getting is:

$\int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=0}^y \sqrt{1+4(x^2+y^2)} dxdy$

Since I am facing some problem to solve this. Is this okay?

Comment: This is correcr, you can change your coordinate system now to compute the integral more easily. Or you could consider an alternate paramterization of your surface that might be easier to integrate and compute the alternate $|r_u\times r_v|$

Comment: I don't know parameterization so is there an easier way out?

Comment: Change of coordinate system to compute the integral